# In Gitlab, are you supposed to create a merge request before even starting to work on an issue?

Tags: git, gitlab, workflow, issue-tracking, git-workflow

When I click on the issue I've just been assigned to, the default action is "Create merge request".
I don't understand why. Wouldn't it make more sense to start working on the issue before issuing a merge request? There's another possible action "Create branch". That makes more sense to me. Should I select that option instead?

Comment: I don't get it either, isn't a merge request supposed to be a request to be merged? So if you don't intend to request a merge yet, why open a merge request?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, I think it's really question of personal preference or team workflow.

The created merge request automatically gets the *work in progress* status, and its title will start with "*Draft: ...*". I'll we speak for myself but I'm using the merge request page as an entrypoint for different things. It lets me know:

- who is working on what (without having to filter the list of issues by assignee)
- what is the status of the ongoing tasks
- which MR are ready to be reviewed (the ones not starting with "Draft")

We are trying to systematically have a look on Merge Requests before taking a new issue. I find this overview interesting.

I know there are other ways to have these pieces of information, so it's totally up to you. And I can understand that having empty merge requests can be disturbing or even confusing for large teams tackling a lot of issues at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My upvote can't be recorded unfortunately, because of Stackoverflow rules.

Comment: This is how Gitlab formally supports Draft status MRs. They can't even be merged, unless you remove the flag. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/drafts.html